# Rails allowing user signup only if invite code entered is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

So I'm creating a simple app for myself and a small group of people. I would like to restrict access to people that I hand-generate codes for by typing them in myself.

User sign up, log in, logout works, but I don't just want anyone to be able to be register.

*TL;DR*

1. User can sign up but how do I go about setting up a hand-generated code
2. Should be some way to invalidate that code after sign up and see who
   the code is associated with

How can I do this in rails? 
I know the user_model would have to add some sort of field to it, the view/form for it as well, and it would have to be validated (by the controller?). Just stuck.

My thought process is as follows (what i've thought so far)

1. All the invite codes should be kept as an array in a file in the
   rails app?
2. I will have to add a migration that adds `invite_code` to the model/db/view form
3. The controller should validate the presence of the invite code in the view form?

**user/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Retype Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.submit "Create My Account" %>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  log_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
  redirect_to @user
# Handle a successful save.
else
render 'new'
end
end
private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
        :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**user.rb model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

# links this to the question.rb model
has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy


attr_accessor :remember_token
before_save { email.downcase! }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

# Returns the hash digest of the given string.
def User.digest(string)
cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
BCrypt::Engine.cost
BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

# returns a random token
def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

# remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions
def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end

# returns true if the given token matches the digest
def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end

# Forgets a user.
def forget
update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end

end
```

Comment: You need `email` dependent token validation or just simple check would do? Like, if I somehow sneaked out the code and register with my email, is that ok with you?

Comment: I would like to make sure that once the invite code is used, it's stored and assigned to the email that it was signed up with. And once the invite code is used, it should not be able to be used again

Comment: Take a look at the Devise::Invitable module for a good example of how this can be done (and yes you can use it to lock down registration to invited users only).

Answer (score 1):

Well, In that case, you can have a model say `Token` created as below:

```
def self.up
  create_table :tokens do |t
    t.string :code, null: false
    t.boolean :used, default: false
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

And a migration in your `User` table for `token_id`

You can generate new code like, `Token.generate_new_code`

```
def self.generate_new_code
  token = Token.new(code: Digest::SHA1.hexdigest Time.now.to_s)
  token.code if token.save
end
```

And you can understand the rest i.e. accept `code` from registration form, `validate` for `unused` code and set it `true` and `token_id` if the registration is successful.